# How to Fix Unable to start activity ComponentInfo?

Tags: java, android

My problem is when I run app and click on register button suddenly displays the popup: "Force close"

Here is my code:

**Main.java**

```
package com.example.server;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {
    private Button login,register,exit;
    private EditText usertext,passtext;
    public static String res="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        register=(Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        exit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        usertext=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.usertext);
        passtext=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.passtext);
        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                login(usertext.getText().toString(),passtext.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent re=new Intent(Main.this,register.class); 
                startActivity(re);
            }
        });
        exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
    public void login(String user,String pass) {
        new loginserver("http://ujo.ir/login,php",user,pass).execute();
        final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        pd.show();
        final Timer tm=new Timer();
        tm.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if(!res.equals("")){
                            pd.cancel();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            res="";
                            tm.cancel();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 1, 1000);
    }
}
```

**register.java**

```
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream.PutField;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import com.example.server.R.layout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class register extends Activity {    
    public static String res="";
    private Button register,exit;
    private EditText name,family,user,pass,email;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
        exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                register1(name.getText().toString(),family.getText().toString(),user.getText().toString(),pass.getText().toString(),email.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
    public void register1(String name,String family,String user,String pass,String email) {         
        new registerserver("http://ujo.ir/register.php", name, family, user, pass, email).execute();
        final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        pd.show();
        final Timer tm=new Timer();
        tm.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if(!res.equals("")) {
                            pd.cancel();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            res="";
                            tm.cancel();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 1, 1000);            
    }
}
```

**registerserver.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
public class registerserver extends AsyncTask {
    private String Name="";
    private String Family="";
    private String Link="";
    private String User="";
    private String Pass="";
    private String Email="";
    public registerserver(String link,String name,String family,String user,String pass,String email) {
        name=Name;
        family=Family;
        link=Link;
        user=User;
        pass=Pass;
        email=Email;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        try {
            String data=URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Name,"UTF8");
            data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("family","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Family,"UTF8");
            data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(User,"UTF8");
            data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Pass,"UTF8");
            data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Email,"UTF8");
            data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("status","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("a","UTF8");         
            URL mylink=new URL(Link);
            URLConnection connect=mylink.openConnection();
            connect.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr=new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            String line=null;
            while((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            register.res=sb.toString(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return "";
    }
}
```

and lastly, **LogCat**

```html
08-04 21:19:11.704: D/AndroidRuntime(2066): Shutting down VM
08-04 21:19:11.704: W/dalvikvm(2066): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa000f180)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.server/com.example.server.register}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at com.example.server.register.onCreate(register.java:30)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
08-04 21:19:11.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):  ... 11 more
08-04 21:19:11.724: D/dalvikvm(2066): GC_CONCURRENT freed 147K, 3% free 6716K/6919K, paused 0ms+0ms
08-04 21:19:12.174: I/dalvikvm(2066): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-04 21:19:12.174: I/dalvikvm(2066): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-04 21:19:12.234: I/dalvikvm(2066): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-04 21:19:12.234: I/dalvikvm(2066): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you strip it down at all to highlight the problem? Ideally the smallest code that will produce the force close. In so doing you might even find the source of the problem.

Comment: Did you try reading the error message? `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.server.register.onCreate(register.java:30)`. That gives you the exception, the file, and even the line # where it came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to instanciate the Buttons "exit" and "register" in your register class activity. Thats why you get a nullpointer exception. By reading the Logs it is fairly simple to come to that conclusion ;)

And before you move on I would recommend to instanciate all the other elements btw!